# Missing .NET Framework Template Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I have installed .NET Core SDK 2.0.3 version and .NET Core 2.0.0 runtime. But I don't see the **ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework** template option in Visual Studio 2017. Do I need to install anything else?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has changed with the last updates. the two options were considered too confusing so there is now a single template option that takes you to a dialog that lets you select between the two frameworks:

[image]