# Why does a new .Net Core Project not allow me to select the Core Framework in VS2017 15.4.3?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a .net core project
How do I specify that I want the framework to be .Net Core 2.0 ?
I am using VS15.4.3 and have .Net Core SDK 2.0.2 installed
[image]

This question is similar to [This question about community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566497/missing-net-framework-template-visual-studio-2017) However I am running the latest version of Visual Studio Professional and the issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you select one of the projects under the the .NET core section, it will be a .net core project. Don't worry about the dropdown at the top.

Once you have created your project, if it is an older version of .net core, you can go to the project properties and update the version to 2.0

Alternatively you can create a new .net core project from your console using the following and then add the project to your solution in visual studio

```
dotnet new console
```

or

```
dotnet new mvc
```

And then run you can also run your project using

```
dotnet run
```

Comment: Kinda annoying right? I don't understand why they didn't change that dropdown to contain the .NET Core frameworks available when selecting a core project (or .NET Standard in the standard libraries).

Comment: Yes. At first I too was looking for core options there. But I guess the dropdown is meant for something else for handling older framework types. However when you select the project, you get another window now where you can select the version

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I think that might depend on what template you choose. I was not getting another window with the Dev Express template

Comment: which template were you trying?